# how to share video file in mysite to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, video

Now currently i am working on a french social networking site. I have small problem in my site i.e., in my site there is module of albums , In this we can upload videos and photos. My client requirement is when we are displaying those photos and video's need to keep face book share.i wrote the code for both image and video but it is working for only images, Not working for videos.these videos are not youtube videos .In my site i installed flash video by that we are playing that video in my site.

Code :

```
<meta name="medium" content="video" />
<meta name="title" content="title of that video"/>
<meta name="description" content="Description"/>
<link rel="image_src" content="http://mysite.com/users/forum/forum_videos/previews/previewimage.jpg" />
<link rel="video_src" href="http://mysite.com/player-viral.swf?file=http://mysite.com/users/forum/forum_videos/videos/JanWed2010_072112.flv"/>
<meta name="video_height" content="240" />
<meta name="video_width" content="320" />
<meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

please suggest me if the above code is correct or not

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds quite the same like another user on here called Stalin with the same written language flaws asking for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171099/image-sharing-from-mysite-to-facebook-profile-using-php
Quite honestly you really need to look into the Facebook PHP SDKs found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... where mymovie.flv is the file that you want to play.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FlowPlayer.swf"
    width="320" height="263" id="FlowPlayer">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"/>
  <param name="movie" value="FlowPlayer.swf"/>
  <param name="quality" value="high"/>
  <param name="scale" value="noScale"/>
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
  <param name="flashvars"
    value="videoFile=mymovie.flv"/>
</object>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply , But can u explain where i need to keep this code .Actually when we click on facebook share button it will get data from the metatags.




For example if we want to share an image, then it will take the title of the imagefrom this <meta name="title" content="title of that video"/> and description from this <meta name="description" content="Description"/> and image is from <link rel="image_src" content="http://mysite.com/users/forum/forum_videos/previews/previewimage.jpg" />

So can you explain how i need to share that video.

Thanks
P Rajkumar